# Simplify nested promises within loops and closures

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, nested, closures

I wrote a ~50 lines script to perform housekeeping on MySQL databases. I'm afraid my code exhibits anti-patterns as it rapidly escalates to an unreadable mess for the simple functions it performs.

I'd like some opinions for improving readability.
The full script is at the bottom of this post to give an idea.

### Spotlight on the problem

The excessive nesting is caused by patterns like this repeated over and over: (snippet taken from script)

```
sql.query("show databases")
.then(function(rows) {
    for (var r of rows) {
        var db = r.Database;

        (function(db) {
            sql.query("show tables in " + db)
            .then(function(rows) {
            // [...]
            }
        })(db);
    }
});
```

I'm nesting one promise under the other within both a `for` loop and a closure. The loop is needed to iterate across all results from `sql.query()`, and the closure is necessary to pass the value of `db` to the lower promise; without the closure, the loop would complete even before the nested promise executes at all, so `db` would always contain only the last element of the loop, preventing the nested promise from reading each value of `db`.

### Full script

```
var mysql     = require("promise-mysql");
var validator = require("mysql-validator");  // simple library to validate against mysql data types

var ignoreDbs  = [ "information_schema" ],
    multiplier = 2,  // numeric records multiplier to check out-of-range proximity
    exitStatus = {'ok': 0, 'nearOutOfRange': 1, 'systemError': 2};

(function() {
    var sql,

        mysqlHost = "localhost",
        mysqlUser = "user",
        mysqlPass = "";

    mysql.createConnection({
        host:     mysqlHost,
        user:     mysqlUser,
        password: mysqlPass
    }).then(function(connection) {
        sql = connection;
    })

   .then(function() {
    sql.query("show databases")
    .then(function(rows) {
        for (var r of rows) {
        var db = r.Database;

        if (ignoreDbs.indexOf(db) != -1) continue;
        (function(db) {
            sql.query("show tables in " + db)
            .then(function(rows) {
            for (var r of rows) {
                var table = r["Tables_in_" + db];

                (function(table) {
                sql.query("describe " + db + "." + table)
                    .then(function(rows) {
                    for (var r of rows) {
                    (function(r) {
                        var field = r.Field,
                            type  = r.Type,   // eg: decimal(10,2)
                                                query = "select " + field + " from " + db + "." + table + " ";

                        if (table != "nonce") query += "order by date desc limit 1000";

                        sql.query(query)
                        .then(function(rows) {
                        for (var r of rows) {
                            var record, err;

                            // remove decimal part, only integer range is checked
                            record = Math.trunc(r[field]);
                            err = validator.check(record * multiplier, type);
                            if (err) {
                            console.log(err.message);
                            process.exit(exitStatus.nearOutOfRange);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    })(r);
                    }
                });
                })(table);
            }
            });
        })(db);
        }
    });
    })
    .then(function() {
    // if (sql != null) sql.end();  // may not exit process here: sql connection terminates before async functions above
    //process.exit(exitStatus.ok);  //
    });
})();
```

### Trivia

The purpose of the script is to automatically and periodically monitor if any record stored in any row, table and database in MySQL is approaching the out-of-range limit for its specific data type. Several other processes connected to MySQL continuously insert new numeric data with increasing values and nonces; this script is a central point where to check for such numeric limits. The script would then be attached to Munin for continuous monitoring and alerting.

---

### Update: Revised script

As suggested by @Kqcef I modularized the anonymous functions out of the promise nest, and used `let` to avoid the explicit nesting of an additional function to preserve variable context.

Still this is excessively verbose, previously I wrote the same script in Bash in about 40 lines, but performance was screaming for a port to nodejs.

```
"use strict";

var mysql     = require("promise-mysql");
var validator = require("mysql-validator");  // a simple library to validate against mysql data types

var ignoreDbs  = [ "information_schema" ],
    multiplier = 2,  // numeric records multiplier to check out-of-range proximity
    exitStatus = {'ok': 0, 'nearOutOfRange': 1, 'systemError': 2};

var mysqlHost = "localhost",
    mysqlUser = "btc",
    mysqlPass = "";

// return array of DBs strings
function getDatabases(sql) {
    return sql.query("show databases")
    .then(function(rows) {
        var dbs = [];

        for (var r of rows)
            dbs.push(r.Database);

        return dbs;
    });
}

// return array of tables strings
function getTables(sql, db) {
    return sql.query("show tables in " + db)
    .then(function(rows) {
        var tables = [];

        for (var r of rows)
            tables.push(r["Tables_in_" + db]);

        return tables;
    });
}

// return array of descriptions
function getTableDescription(sql, db, table) {
    return sql.query("describe " + db + "." + table)
    .then(function(rows) {
        var descrs = [];

        for (var r of rows) {
            descrs.push({ 'field': r.Field,    // eg: price
                          'type':  r.Type});   // eg: decimal(10,2)
        }

        return descrs;
    });
}

// return err object
function validateRecord(record, type) {
    var record, err;

    if (typeof record != "number") {
        console.log("error: record is not numeric.");
        process.exit(exitStatus.systemError);
    }

    // remove decimal part, only integer range is checked
    record = Math.trunc(record);
    err = validator.check(record * multiplier, type);

    return err;
}

(function() {
    var sql;

    mysql.createConnection({
        host:     mysqlHost,
        user:     mysqlUser,
        password: mysqlPass
    }).then(function(connection) {
        sql = connection;
    })

    .then(function() {
        return getDatabases(sql)
    })
    .then(function(dbs) {
        dbs.forEach(function(db) {
            if (ignoreDbs.indexOf(db) != -1) return;
            getTables(sql, db)
            .then(function(tables) {
                tables.forEach(function(table) {
                    getTableDescription(sql, db, table)
                    .then(function(descrs) {
                        descrs.forEach(function(descr) {
                            let field = descr.field,
                                type  = descr.type,
                                query = "select " + descr.field + " from " + db + "." + table + " ";

                            if (table != "nonce") query += "order by date desc limit 1000";

                            sql.query(query)
                            .then(function(rows) {
                                rows.forEach(function(row) {
                                    let err = validateRecord(row[field], type);
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log(err.message);
                                        process.exit(exitStatus.nearOutOfRange);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });


/*
    .then(function() {
        //if (sql != null) sql.end();
        //process.exit(exitStatus.ok);
    });
*/
})();
```

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your main issue *may* be the number of "simultaneous" requests happening. e.g. if there are 5 db's each with with 5 tables each with 5 fields, there could be 125 "simultaneous" `"select " + field + " from " + db + "." + table` requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Jaromanda in terms of using `let` in your for loops to block scope the values and avoid your usage of an immediately-invoked function, which, while totally fine in terms of functionality, is decidedly less readable.

In terms of best practices and avoiding anti-patterns, one of the most important things you can strive for in terms of writing 'good' code is building modularized, reusable blocks of code. As it stands, your code has 5 or 6 anonymous functions that exist nowhere but within your chain of promise callbacks. If you were to declare those as functions outside of that chain, not only does that improve the maintainability of your code (you can test each individual one), but, if their names are clearly indicative of their purposes, would make for a very readable promise chain.

(Updated based on User Question)

Rather than leaving inner functions...

```
function getTableDescription(sql, db, table) {
    return sql.query("describe " + db + "." + table)
    .then(function(rows) {
        var descrs = [];

        for (var r of rows) {
            descrs.push({ 'field': r.Field,    // eg: price
                          'type':  r.Type});   // eg: decimal(10,2)
        }

        return descrs;
    });
}
```

...you can easily strip that out so that your code is self-documenting:

```
function collectDescriptionsFromRows(rows) {
  var descriptions = [];
  for (var row of rows) {
    descriptions.push({'field': row.Field, 'type': row.Type});
  }
  return descriptions;
}

function getTableDescription(sql, db, table) {
    return sql.query("describe " + db + "." + table)
    .then(collectDescriptionsFromRows);
}
```

Also, if you ever find yourself doing data collection from one array to another, it's extremely helpful to get used to using built-in higher order functions (map, filter, reduce). Instead of the `collectDescriptionsFromRows` I just listed, it could be simplified to:

```
function collectDescriptionsFromRows(rows) {
  return rows.map(row => { 'field': row.Field, 'type':  row.Type});
}
```

Much less verbose, much more readable. Your code and promise-chain will shrink and read more like a step-by-step list of instructions if you continue to extract those anonymous functions in the chain. Anywhere you see `function(`...there is more extracting to do! You can also do some damage (positively) by extracting all the data you need to begin with and use local logic to boil it down to what you need, rather than making several queries. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the revised script as per your suggestion.

Comment: Cool, let me know if this answered your question!